# facebook open graph dialog is not displayed

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-android-sdk

I am trying to implement the open graph dialog using the SDK version 4.2.0.

I updated my manifest :

```
 <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
          android:label="@string/app_name" />

      <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider//My app id//"
          android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider" 
          android:exported="true" />
```

I initiate the sdk in the first activity :
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

I prepare my open Graph actions and objects :

```
ShareOpenGraphObject fbRoute = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
.putString("og:type", "me/objects/fbclimbmystats:route")
.putString("og:title", "")
.putString("name", name)
.putString("grade", grade.getDisplayableGrade(pPrefs, type))
.putString("location", spotName)
.build();   

ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
.setActionType("route.climb")
.putObject("route", fbRoute)
.build();

ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
.setPreviewPropertyName("route")
.setAction(action)
.build();
```

and display it :
    ShareDialog.show(this, content);

My problem is that the dialog does not even get displayed. Not even for a second and the log cat does not give much information.

Additional info:
 - I havent been through the process of approving my app on facebook yet (I can't figure how to do that either...). Should I start with that?

What else did I miss?

Thanks guys.

Comment: your og:type should be just "fbclimbmystats:route"

Comment: @MingLi Thanks for the tip but it did not solve my problem. The Open Graph dialog is still not displayed. From a UI point of view, absolutely nothing happens when I click the button.

Comment: Have you tried one of the sample projects bundled with the SDK? did that work for you? if so, try to compare both projects and take it from there.

Answer (score 2):

So I solved my problem and here is my code with some lessons learned.

My Manifest:

```
 <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
      android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
      android:label="@string/app_name" />

    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationName"
               android:value="@string/facebook_app_name" />

    <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider{facebook_app_id}"
      android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider" 
      android:exported="true" />
```

My code to generate the open graph Object:

```
//Create the opengraph object and set the attributes for the route
ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder fbRouteBuilder = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder();
fbRouteBuilder.putString("og:type", "fbclimbmystats:route"); // keep the ":"

//The route title 
String fbTitle = name!= null && !name.isEmpty() ? name : "Congrats";
fbRouteBuilder.putString("og:title", fbTitle);

//The route name
if (name!=null && !name.isEmpty())
    fbRouteBuilder.putString("route:name", "le nom");

//the route grade. The route will always have a grade
fbRouteBuilder.putString("route:grade", grade.getDisplayableGrade(pPrefs, type));

//The location will always have a name
fbRouteBuilder.putString("route:location", spotName);

ShareOpenGraphObject fbRoute = fbRouteBuilder.build();
```

Then the Action:

```
//We build the action CLIMB with the Object juste created above
ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder actionBuilder = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder();

switch (completion){
case Route.COMPLETION_ON_SIGHT:
    actionBuilder.setActionType("fbclimbmystats:on_sight"); //name space needed
    break;
case Route.COMPLETION_FLASH:
    actionBuilder.setActionType("fbclimbmystats:flash");
    break;
default :
    actionBuilder.setActionType("fbclimbmystats:climb");
}

actionBuilder.putObject("route", fbRoute); 
ShareOpenGraphAction action = actionBuilder.build();
```

And finally the content object :

```
ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder contentBuilder = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder();
    contentBuilder.setPreviewPropertyName("route"); // No namespace here
    contentBuilder.setAction(action);
    ShareOpenGraphContent content =  contentBuilder.build();
```

Here is a bit of knowledge acquired through trial and error:

- Do not give attributes if they are not used in a sentence in the graph.
- Do not give empty attributes (pass null string)
- the attribute "namespace.object" is incorrect. Always use "namespace:object"
- For custom attributes of object, call them using "object:attribute"